Jabref abstract field doesn't render LaTex
I'm using Jabref for dealing with my references. One of the fields of Jabref is "abstract. I would like to know if this field is able to render some Latex command. The image shows what I'm trying and the (bad) results. I would like to read the abstract, including formulae, inside Jabref.
Does someone know if Jabref can render Latex?

Jabref doesn't render TeX input.

You can export the references with JabRef in several formats but in  LaTeX is just a donor of the .bib file with the raw data, it has not anything to say about the final style.
